# Get the Views of Athena editor using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

On Athena query editor there is the Tables list section and the Views list section. Is there a way to obtain the Views list section using python's boto3 module? (get view names and the actual sql that makes up the view)

From what I see, we can only obtain the Saved Queries list using the "list_named_queries" function:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#client

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Athena uses the **AWS Glue Data Catalog**.

Therefore, you can **obtain the list of tables** by using [`get_tables()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_tables) in the AWS Glue API.

It seems to include a few fields that are specifically populated by Views (eg `ViewOriginalText`) so you should be able to identify **which ones are Views** rather than Tables.